# Passing multiple properties in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm quite new with VueJS. I'm working on a new project with VueCLI3 & VuetifyJS.

I'm trying to create a reusable components based on VuetifyJS components and would like to make things easier by passing multiple props in a separate file to render them at once in my new component files.
I found this article that explains a technique to achieve such thing.

https://alligator.io/vuejs/passing-multiple-properties/

Every time I need to render them I must import my seperate file.

component1.vue

```
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind='buttonProps'>
    Button 1
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  import { buttonProps } from './props.js';

  export default {
    data: () => ({ buttonProps })
  }
</script>
```

component2.vue

```
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind='buttonProps'>
    Button 2
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  import { buttonProps } from './props.js';

  export default {
    data: () => ({ buttonProps })
  }
</script>
```

Is there any way to register the file globally so it allows me to use it anywhere in the app like this?

props.js

```
export const buttonProps = {
  color: 'primary',
  small: true,
  outline: true,
  block: true,
  ripple: true,
  href: 'https://alligator.io'
}
```

main.js

```
import Props from 'props.js';
```

component3.vue

```
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind='buttonProps'>
    Button 3
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  ... // no import needed
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `mixin` and register that mixin globally.

**buttonPropsMixin**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      buttonProps: {
        color: 'primary',
        small: true,
        outline: true,
        block: true,
        ripple: true,
        href: 'https://alligator.io'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import buttonPropsMixin from '...';

Vue.mixin(buttonPropsMixin)
```

**Note** That each vue component has its own `buttonProps`, so if you change in one component the `color` it will *not* affect the other components!
If you want `buttonProps` to have the same state across all your components you can go the `vuex` way as Igor mentioned and use it with an mixin where you define the `mapGetters` in that mixin.

Comment: Thank you this works great for me, you just saved me ton of times!

Comment: Another question, I would like to register all mixins globally in a separate file like this:

prop.js

    import Vue from 'vue'

    import buttonPropsMixin1 from '...';
    Vue.mixin(buttonPropsMixin1)

    import buttonPropsMixin2 from '...';
    Vue.mixin(buttonPropsMixin2)

and then import this file to my main.js file

main.js

    import prop from './prop.js';

But i got this error

    error: 'prop' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/main.js

Do I have to do this?

    new Vue({
      prop,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')

Comment: Check out this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5vqlxl2ll Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if it is possible to have hyphens in my v-bind? Instead of writing this v-bind="ed_checkbox" I would like to write v-bind="ed-checkbox"

Answer (score 0):

If data in `props.js` doesn't need to be reactive and all the components are children of some root component you could do this:

main.js:

```
import buttonProps from 'props.js';

new Vue({
  el: rootComponentElement,
  buttonProps: buttonProps,
  render: h => h(rootComponent)
})
```

component.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-btn v-bind='$root.$options.buttonProps'>
    Button 3
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
  ... // no import needed
</script>
```

Otherwise I would advice you to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or use the global bus method described [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/).

Comment: thank you for your answer but @D-F found the exact solution I needed for my project.